# regular expression to match firstname.lastname or just firstname with length limit

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regex to use in .net that will match a user name as firstname or firstname.lastname with a maxlength of 50 characters. The firstname case is easy but with firstname.lastname I can't figure out how to only allow 50 minus len(firstname.) in the lastname.

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1,50})|([a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+)$
```

will match the firstname case but the second case of firstname.lastname will allow infinite characters in the firstname and lastname.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?i)(?=(?:[a-z]\.?){1,50}$)[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?$
```

Will only match if number of `[a-z]`s is between 1 and 50.

If the total length can never be more than 50, you can use this instead:

```
^(?i)(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?$
```

Comment: Good one +1. FWIW - The length assertion can be shortened to: `(?!.{51})`

Comment: I think with the change from @ridgerunner this is the cleanest ^(?i)(?!.{51})[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)?$

Comment: I tested this in .net server side code and it works fine, however I used the expression in a RegularExpressionValidator and I receive this error message in Firebug `invalid quantifier ?i)(?!.{6})[a-z]+(?:[.][a-z]+)?$)` Apparently Javascript doesn't support named captures so the expression has to be `^(?!.{51})[a-zA-Z]+(?:[.][a-zA-Z]+)?$` the difference being I took out the ignore case part.

Answer (score 2):

Easily done. Here is a C# snippet with a commented regex:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(userNameString, 
    @"# Match username with max length of 50 chars
    ^            # Anchor to start of string.
    (?!.{51})    # Assert length is 50 or less.
    [A-Za-z]+    # First name.
    (?:          # Optional second name.
      \.         # Required dot separator.
      [A-Za-z]+  # Last name.
    )?           # Last name is optional.
    $            # Anchor to end of string.
    ", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Valid username
} else {
    // Invalid username
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it.

```
^(?:([a-zA-Z]{1,50})|(?=.{1,51}$)[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Essentially, I added a lookaround saying match (without capturing) 1-51 chars and then the end of line. I used 51 because I'm assuming that the `.` should count in the length calculation.

Comment: Would match on string `foo#¤%&/bar`. Guess why. ;-)

Comment: That seems to allow any number of letters without a period or any number of letters followed by any number of periods followed by any number of letters. Also allows any number of periods at any position between letters. Even worse than what I had.

Comment: @Wayland Your initial regex actually had the same issues.  http://codepad.org/PWhpCNv3

Comment: @Jacob I see what you mean about my expression and your edit seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a two-step validation would be so much easier and I don't see a reason to avoid it.

Comment: Do you mean by validating the length in code after the regex passes?